# Como faço para ajustar o tamanho dos itens de um TListView

Tags: delphi, listview, firemonkey

Gostaria de pedir ajuda a vocês sobre uma dificuldade que estou enfrentando.

O `TListView` está com a configuração do `Appearance` como `DynamicAppearance`.

[image: Lista com produtos]

Eu gostaria de quebrar dos produtos que tiverem adicionais, por exemplo, o primeiro produto tem 2 adicionais e eu gostaria de quebrar a linha para cada adicional e redimensionar a linha da lista.

Comment: Esta TListView é do Firemonkey ou do VCL?

Comment: É do Firemonkey.

Answer (score 0):

Para quebrar os produtos adicionais podes substituir a virgula por um *chr(13)*, por exemplo. Não sei se o texto é criado por ti ou não, mas se nao for podes usar um *ReplaceStr(detail,',',chr(13))*

Quanto à altura do item, cada *TListView* item tem uma propriedade *Height* que podes alterar e assim uns ficarem maiores que outros. Talvez possas contar o numero de virgulas ou de produtos adicionais e aumentar a linha X% para cada um.

Comment: Quando eu modifico o tamanho do height ele não modifica visualmente..

O código que estou utilizando é este:

Comment: lvCarrinho.Items[lvCarrinho.Selected.Index].Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('adicionais').Height := lvCarrinho.Items[lvCarrinho.Selected.Index].Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('adicionais').Height * cdsCarrinhoAdicionais.RecordCount;

Comment: Podes por o codigo de preenchimento da ListView?

Comment: A lista está ligada com o data set pelo bind visually. Então eu só preencho o data set e recarrego.

Comment: Não costumo usar os bindings, mas presumo que então após preecnheres o dataset, podes fazer um for pelos items da TListView e fazer o que indiquei anteriormente. 
Experimenta mudar a altura total do ITEM (lvCarrinho.Items[lvCarrinho.Selected.Index].Height) e nao do item dos details em especifico (lvCarrinho.Items[lvCarrinho.Selected.Index].Objects.FindObje‌​ctT<TListItemText>('‌​adicionais').Height)

Comment: tentei modificar somente a altura do item como especificado, mas não encontrei resultados, por mais que o número seja alterado na tela não muda nada..

Answer (score 0):

Voce deve usar a função `UpdateObjects` para ajustar o item do Listview.

Eu uso para ajustar a largura, vc pode ajustar para a altura.

Eu faço assim:

```
var
  txt: TListItemText;
begin
  with AItem do
  begin
    txt := TListItemText(AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('txtDescricao'));
    txt.Width := lstListagem.Width - txt.PlaceOffset.X - 8;
  end;
```